# Docker Jetty Webserver: only showing war contents instead of running server

Tags: docker, jetty, vaadin, war

maybe someone can help me with my problem:

I've got a running docker and deployed a .war file to my jetty webapps folder at (/var/lib/jett/webapps)

This exact .war file is running at other machines, but the one i'm currently working on wont execute the .war/ start the webserver.

When i open a browser and navigate to myIP:Portnumber/myWarFile jetty only shows me the files inside the .war, but a cant access the actual website.

Is there any configuration that i might have missed?

My Docker config for jetty looks like this:

```css
docker run --name zynq --restart always -d -p 9999:8080 -v /var/lib/jetty/webapps:/var/lib/jetty/webapps -v /home/sven/Desktop/jetty:/home/sven/Desktop/jetty jetty
```

Last lines of verbose output when starting the docker jetty container:

```css
ty/jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-MESSE072_war-_MESSE072-any-3951420110201373021/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/vaadin-split-layout-4.1.0.jar!/META-INF/resources],AVAILABLE}{/var/lib/jetty/webapps/MESSE072.war}
2022-09-12 08:58:13.501:INFO :oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@dfb0738{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2022-09-12 08:58:13.509:INFO :oejs.Server:main: Started Server@184cf7cf{STARTING}[11.0.11,sto=5000] @1413ms
```

Any clue, why this might not work?
Thanks alot for any ideas!

Comment: Did you build for production? I get the feeling you might be missing the index.html file.

Comment: Maybe you need to run this as WAR for some reason and I do not know if you are using Spring Boot or not but if you are a great way is to bundle the web application server within the jar and start that from Docker.